# Find the value of: $z=(-1)^{2\over 3}$ and $z=i^{1\over 3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This question in complex analysis :

Find the value of:

(i) $z=(-1)^{2\over 3}$

(ii) $z=i^{1\over 3}$

- For (i) I think:

$z^3=(-1)^2$

$z^3=i^4$

$z^3=1$

I don't want the roots, i want the value of $z$ but I don't know how can I complete this.

- for (ii)

$z^3=i$

What else?

Comment: How do you define $z^n$ when $z$ is complex, not a nonnegative real number, and $n$ is not an integer?

Comment: Because in (i) $x=-1$ and $y=0$ then $\theta=arctan{-y\over x}=arctan(0)=0$

Comment: In (ii) i use the same way but $x=0$ and $y=1$

Comment: Are your comments meant to answer my query?

Comment: Oh no, i am sorry.

Comment: OK, and what about answering the mathematical question in my first comment?

Comment: Are you mean $z^{n}=r^{n}e^{i\theta}=r^{n}[cos{{\theta+2k\pi}\over n}+sin{{\theta+2k\pi}\over n}]$ ?

Comment: ?? This. Does. Not. Make. Any. Sense.

Comment: Sorry I don't speak English well, this de moaver theorem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$\left(-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=\left(\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi k_1\right)i}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=\left|-1\right|^{\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{2}{3}\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi k_1\right)i}=e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}\left(1+2k_1\right)i}$$
   Where $k_1\in\mathbb{Z}$
2. $$i^{\frac{1}{3}}=\left(\left|i\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(i\right)+2\pi k_2\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=\left|i\right|^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(\arg\left(i\right)+2\pi k_2\right)i}=e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}+2k_2\right)i}$$
   Where $k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now, use Euler's formula:

$$e^{\varphi i}=\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i$$

Comment: How can I calculate $arg(-1)$ and $arg(-i)$ ?  I think : $z=(-1)^{2\over 3}$ , $x=-1$ and $y=0$ then $\theta=arctan ({-y\over x})=arctan(-\infty)={-\pi\over2}$ true ?

Comment: @Dima No, that's is not true. $\arg(-1)=\pi$

Comment: Sorry but How ? what's the rule ?

Comment: @Dima look at this website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now.

Comment: @Dima You're welcome. I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write $-1$ and $i$ as complex numbers in polar form $r e^{i\phi}$. Then raising to some power p will yield $r^p e^{i p \phi}$. For both of these cases $r=1$. You might want to use $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi +i\sin\phi$.

Comment: In (i) $\theta=0$ (ii) $\theta=\pi\over 2$ true ?

Comment: Because in (i) $x=-1$ and $y=0$ then $\theta=arctan{-y\over x}=arctan(0)=0$ , and In (ii) i use the same way but with $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: True or false?, and thank you

Comment: $-1=e^{i\pi}$. You would need to use what in many programming languages is called arctan2 or atan2 functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2